# This question seems simple but I can't wrap my head around it

Tags: limits, derivatives

> Determine the two points on the graph $y = x^4 - 2x^2 - x$ which share a common tangent.

I tried plotting the graph out but I couldn't really wrap my head around how $2$ points can have the same tangent. I could be missing something completely obvious but I would really appreciate if someone could solve it and walk me through it.

Comment: Plotting the graph is really the way forward. Perhaps find a computer program or website to do it for you. You will see that there are some points such that the tangent line at that point will never touch the graph anywhere else, no matter how long you extend it, and points where the tangent line at that point clearly intersects the graph somewhere else if you extend it long enough. Somewhere in between these 'generic' cases must be a special boundary case: a point whose tangent touches but does not intersect the graph a second time somewhere else.

Comment: When that happens this line, which we thought about as the tangent in the first point must also be the tangent in the second point where it touches

Comment: Maybe it's easier to see how two points can have the same tangent if you think about a function like $\sin x$, where the points at $x = \frac 12 \pi, \frac 52 \pi$ have a common tangent (the line $y = 1$). It's similar here, because the quartic has two "round bits" that stick out at the bottom, which can be joined by a tangent.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I use a trick in my answer to  show how to find the two lines that are tangent, each infinitely often, to $$y = \frac{x}{2} + \sin x $$

Answer (score 4):

Let the common tangent be $y=kx+m$, whose intersection points with the curve are given by,

$$x^4-2x^2-(1+k)x-m=(x^2-1)^2-(1+k)x-(m+1)=0$$

Given that there are two points that share the tangent line, the above equation has to have exactly two roots, which requires that it has the form of a complete square, i.e. $k=m=-1$.

Thus, the two points are $(1,-2)$ and $(-1,0)$, with the tangent line $y=-x-1$.

Comment: In general, you want to find the solution of form $P(x)(x-p)^2(x-q)^2$, and then show that $P(x)=1$, $p=-q$ and then go for $(x^2-1)^2$

Comment: I see how you got to the second equation but I don't get why k and m would both be equal to -1. @VasilyMitch is P(x) the notation for the expression or is it part of it?

Comment: @JawadGill - $k=m=-1$ comes from $-(k+1)x-(m+1) = 0$ because the equation has to be complete square $(x^2-1)^2$ to assure only two roots.

Comment: In your solution it is not clear how you go from "has exactly two roots" to "must be a perfect square". The polynomial $(x-1)^3(x+1)$ also has exactly two roots, but it is not a perfect square.

Comment: $y=1$ also has exactly two intersections with the given curve.

Comment: Note that there is no $x^3$ term, which eliminates the mentioned possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

**It's a trick.** We don't need calculus, just "incidence."

If we begin with $$   y = (x^2 - 1)^2 = x^4 - 2 x^2 + 1 $$
we see that the $x$ axis is tangent to the graph twice, at $x = \pm 1$

Next, we will subtract off a linear function, namely $\color{red}{x+1},$ as your function is
$$ (x^2 - 1)^2 - x - 1 = x^4 - 2 x^2 - x $$

Ignoring questions of slope, the line $y = 0 - x - 1$ or
$$ y = -x - 1 $$
intersects your graph exactly twice. Therefore it really is tangent twice.

[image]

[image]

One of the comments suggests looking at the (repeat) tangents to $y = \sin x,$ namely $y = 1$ and $y = -1.$  Here we use the same trick to find lines that are tangent, infinitely often, to $$y = \frac{x}{2} + \sin x $$
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I just made a guess ( guided by the idea described in the comment by @Izaak van Dongen): the derivative is of course
$$y'=4x^3-4x-1$$
and $y'=-1$ is easy to solve: $x=0$ or $x=1$ or $x=-1$ and the latter two correspond to tangents with slope $-1$ to the points $(1|-2)$ and $(-1|0)$ and both tangents turn out to be one and the same with the equation:
$$y=-x-1$$
which is easy to check.

Answer (score 1):

For the equation $\hat y=k\hat x+b$ of tangent at point $x$ we know that:
$$
k=4x^3-4x^2-1,\qquad\text{and}\qquad b=-3x^4+2x^2
$$

Let those points have coordinate $x=p$ and $x=q$, then
$$
4p^3-4p-1=4q^3-4q-1,\\
-3p^4+2p^2 = -3q^4+2q^2
$$

Rearragning, we get the following:
$$
(p-q)(p+q)(3p^2+3q^2+2)=0,\\
(p-q)(p^2+pq+q^2-1)=0
$$

The rest I leave for you.

Comment: The second equation has no solution for unequal $p$ and $q$.

Comment: Thanks, there was a typo